# Norm concentration of trigonometric polynomials - Uncertainty principle

Tags: harmonic-analysis, fourier-analysis

Hi all, 
I am interested in the following question (which is quite similar to one I posed a long while ago): Let $P_{N}(t)=\underset{k=-N}{\overset{N}{\sum}}c_{k}e^{ikt}$ be a unit norm trigonometric polynomial, we look at it as a function of $L^{2}\left(\mathbb{T}\right)$.
I'd like to find a direct proof to the fact that there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that for every $N$ and every such polynomial $P_{N}$ we have $\underset{E}{\int}|{P_{N}( t)}|^{2}dt\leq1-\varepsilon$ whenever $E\subset\mathbb{T}$ of measure $|E|=\frac{c}{N}$, and   $c>0$ is some absolute constant. I would be happy with a proof only in the case $E$ is an interval, if it is any different than the general case.
To rephrase the statement; one cannot concentrate the norm of a trigonometric polynomial of degree $N$ on an interval (or any measurable set) of length (measure) of the order of magnitude $\frac{1}{N}$.
Let me comment that there is a result by Nazarov which implies this but it is way too general for my purposes.

Comment: One can get these sorts of bounds by using reproducing formulae coming from Littlewood-Paley theory, e.g. expressing $P_N = P_N * K_N$ where $K_N$ is a trig polynomial from -2N to 2N (say) with the coefficients from -N to N equal to 1, and smoothly decaying to zero outside of this.  See e.g. Section 5 of my notes at http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/254a.1.01w/notes1.dvi for some examples of this (I do it on the real line rather than on the circle, but the general idea is the same).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I got the general idea, though I'm still not able to get this sharp lower bound, not even on the real line.

Comment: The post had a misprint. Corrected now.

Comment: Do you want "for all $c>0$ there is $\epsilon>0$" or "there exist
$c>0$ and $\epsilon>0$"?  Even the former should be true but the latter
is easier (at least for an interval).


Comment: Ah, the bound you want is slightly tricky since the analogous statement for the p-adics is false, and so general Fourier-analytic methods are not sufficient.  But I believe one can obtain this result by a compactness and contradiction argument using the fact (special to R) that there are no non-trivial compactly supported functions whose Fourier transform is again compactly supported.  A bit more specifically, suppose the claim is false, take a sequence of counterexamples, and use tools such as the Rellich compactness theorem to extract a counterexample to the previous claim.

Comment: ... hmm, this only seems to work in the interval case (and after a rescaling).  To do the general case seems to require using concentration compactness instead of compactness, which becomes quite fiddly.   It may also be that ideas from the real-valued proof of the Hardy uncertainty principle (see http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/hardys-uncertainty-principle/ ) may be relevant.

Comment: Noam, you can take just $c=1$. Generally the argument should hold for all $c$ with a slight change that the phenomenon occurs for large values of $N$.

Comment: Terry, the compactness argument ignores the measure of the set we are trying to concentrate on, right?
At least in the case of the circle, the measure is critical, i.e. one can concentrate $P_{N}$ on a set of measure $\frac{c}{N^{\alpha}}$ with $\alpha<1$.


Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's talk about algebraic polynomials (just multiply by $z^N$). Let $P$ be a polynomial of degree $N$. Let $\max|P|=1$ and assume that this maximum is attained at some point $p$. Take the disk $D$ of radius $10C/N$ centered at $p$. Note that $z^{-N}P(z)$ satisfies the maximum principle in the complement of the unit disk and $P(z)$ satisfies the maximum principle in the disk itself, so $|P|<e^{10C}$ in $D$. Rescale $D$ to the unit disk $\mathbb D$ and divide by $e^C$. You'll get a bounded by $1$ function $F$ that is $e^{-10C}$ at the center.

Now it is the usual story about subharmonicity of the logarithm of an analytic function. Let $H$ be any closed set on the circular arc passing through the origin on which $F$ is very small. Suppose that the length of $H$ is $1/2$ or more. Consider the function
$$
U(z)=\int_H\log \frac{|z-w|}{|1-\bar wz|}d\ell(w)
$$
It is easy to see that $U\ge -A$ in $\mathbb D$, harmonic in $\mathbb D\setminus H$, $U=0$ on the unit circumference, and $U(0)\le -a$ for some absolute $a,A>0$. If $|F|\le e^{-10CA/a}$ everywhere on $H$, then $\log|F|\le (10C/a)U$ on the boundary of $\mathbb D\setminus H$ and, thereby, $\log|F(0)|\le -10C$, which is not the case. Thus, the minimum of $|F|$ over every set $H$ of length $1/2$ or more is bounded from below. Coming back to the original problem, we see that $|P|$ is bounded from below by some constant depending on $C$ on at least half of the arc of length $10C/N$, so we have plenty of noticeable values outside any set of measure $C/N$.

This trick is pretty old and goes back to Bernstein. There is also another approach due to Remez (moving zeroes and looking at the level sets). You are 100% right when saying that you do not need the Turan type bounds and the related fancy techniques for this problem. :)

Comment: This looks promising but I think you're answering the question for
the sup norm, not the $L^2$ norm which might be smaller by a factor
of order $N^{1/2}$.  Can the analysis be adapted from $L^\infty$ to $L^2$?

Comment: Come on! I showed that $P$ is comparable to its maximum $M$ on a set of measure $10C/N$. Now just think a tiny bit. The integral of $|f|^2$ over any set E of measure $C/N$ is at most $CM^2/N$. However, the integral over the remaining part of the set of measure $10C/N$ is also at least $cM^2/N$, so the outside of E carries a noticeable part of the norm, as you wanted. That is the beauty of working with measurable sets instead of intervals: you actually get estimates for the distribution function and can switch from $L^\infty$ bounds to bounds in other norms at no cost whatsoever.   

Comment: You say this is a classical approach. Can you refer me to Bernstein's and Remez's relevant papers?

Comment: No. This is my weak point: I remember the proofs well, I remember names with some degree of accuracy, I do not remember references at all. So, I'll have to do exactly the same google or mathscinet search to answer this question as you can do yourself spending the same amount of time :(.

Comment: I will give the search another try, thanks anyway :). On a more concrete note, can you please explain where does the bound $\left|P\right|<e^{10C}$ in $D$ come from? I must be missing something.

Comment: In $D$ we have $|z|^N\le e^{10C}$ and $|P(z)|\le |z|^N$ outside the unit disk by the maximum principle for the function $P(z)z^{-N}$.

Comment: Thanks, this point is clear now. I really want to get this right so I'm going to ask a couple of question more, I hope it is ok:
1.By "rescale $D$ to the unit disk" you mean compose $P$ with two mobius transformations, first translation of the point $p$ to the origin and then rescale. Is that right?
2.The fact that $U(0)<-a$ for some $a>0$ should require at least for part of the set $H$ to be inside the unit disk, otherwise, if $H$ is all outside, $U(0)$ would be positive, no?


Comment: 3. Where exactly in the proof do you use the fact that $H$ has length $\frac{1}{2}$ or more? why not take $H$ shorter? where does it fail?


Comment: 1) Yes, translate $p$ to the origin and blow the radius up to $1$. 2) Yes, $H$ is a subset of the image of the original piece of the unit circumference inside $D$ (so now it is almost a diameter of the unit disk, but slightly curved). 3) In order to get the value of the integral $-a$ or less at $0$, we need some noticeable measure to integrate over. 

Comment: In that case $H$ cannot be just any closed set of length at least $\frac{1}{2}$, it is restricted to be "close" to a point where the maximum of $|P|$ is attained (where it is reasonable to think that $|P|$ would be bounded below intuitively, by a continuity argument). Moreover I am wondering, if , as written, the minimum of $|F|$ is bounded below over every set $H$ of length at least $\frac{1}{2}$, doesn't this imply $F$ never vanishes on the unit circumference (one can just cover the whole perimeter with such sets)? again it seems like I got something wrong.

Comment: Honestly, did you bother to draw a picture? $H$ has length $1/2$ and lies in the blown up circle. Before the blow up, $H$ is a subset of the arc of the unit circle lying inside $D$ and has length at least $5C/N$.